# What happens when your crew is full and you're awarded a new crew member?

Tags: star-trek-timelines

I have been told you can sometimes get 3 crew members, possibly more, from a 10-item portal purchase. Because of this, I've been keeping my crew at 22 out of 25 for a while now, because I'm scared I may not have the chance to dismiss someone less valuable than one of the awards.

When your crew roster is full, and you are awarded a new character, what happens? Do you have the opportunity to manage crew, or does it just say "no more room" or something? What if you're awarded two characters, and only have one open crew slot?

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm just too scared to test. The crew members I might miss out on are just too rare, and if they appear and I can't accept them I might not see them again for a depressingly long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finally happened. I accidentally accrued a full roster during the current "They Came From The Holodeck!" event, and when I received a new character, I saw the following screen when I went to manage my crew:

[image: full roster screen]

So apparently...

- You get the new crew member
- You cannot use the new crew until another is dismissed
- You have one week to dismiss someone or the new crew is automatically dismissed
- You have the option to buy 5 more crew slots for 250000 credits

Answer (score 0):

The first time you buy extra slots,  you pay credits. From there the cost just goes up, and it will start requiring you to hand over dilithium to open up more slots.